# C `signal` has too few arguments

Tags: c, signals, wait, semaphore, dining-philosopher

I am working on a problem where I am supposed to implement an example of the dining philosopher paradigm. **Note**: Yes this a homework assignment, before anyone asks.

I am not asking for a solution though. I am confused because this `Philosopher` function that was supplied below by my teacher is theoretically supposed to work. `wait` and `signal` are the function used in C for OS system calls.

I have included them using:

```
/* Wait and Signal */
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

struct semaphore
{
    int count = 1;
    struct PCB *Sem_Queue ;
};
struct semaphore Forks[5];

Philosopher()
{
    i = getPID() ;
    while (1)
    {
        think ();
        wait (Forks[i]);
        wait (Forks[(i+1) % 5]);
        eat ();
        signal (Forks[i]);
        signal (Forks[(i + 1) % 5]);
    }
}
```

However, when compiled I get the error:

```
Main.c:38:19: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 1
                signal (Forks[i]);
```

Comment: philosopher needs to be declared properly with return data type

Comment: Have you tried to read the manual for the functions you are trying to use? It helps in most of the cases like this.

Comment: I tried adding a `void` type to the function but I still get the same errors.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Can you point me in the right direction to the manual?

Comment: apparently signal takes 2 arguments and you're only supplying one

Comment: I have found that it is supposed to take a `sighandler` as a second parameter. I am unsure of what that means though.

Comment: take a look at the prototype definition and it will tell you what type the sighandler is supposed to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the `wait()` and `signal()` functions called by `Philosopher()` are like the `think()` and `eat()` functions -- intended to be provided by you (or else included with `Philosopher()`).  The name clash between those and two POSIX functions is unfortunate and confusing, but not meaningful.

**Do not** include `signal.h` or `sys/wait.h`.  Instead, provide declarations, by header file or otherwise, for *your* functions of those names, and make sure your implementations are linked into the executable.